# Cordova/PhoneGap - Increase heap size of daemon OSX

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, heap-memory, daemon

I am doing a cordova app. The iOS is running well. But today, I tried it for Android. When I run the command : cordova build android I have the build failed :

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried to find the project gradle.properties, but I can't because it is not built properly..

Do you know where I can set this heap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I placed the following global `gradle.properties` file in the existing `USER_HOME/.gradle` directory:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx3072m
```

It made my Cordova builds **much** faster.

Comment: I am on Mac, I tried to find it already but I didn't succed to find this folder ..

Comment: On my Mac, `env` shows `GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/dave/.gradle`. If `.gradle` folder doesn't exist in your user home directory, you can create it and do `export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/username/.gradle`

Comment: Ok, I just added the folder and did the command line in my shell. There is nothing in the folder .gradle ?

Comment: Put `gradle.properties` in `.gradle` folder

Comment: Ok I did, added the line you gave, but I have the same error with heap blocked to 910MB ..

Comment: strange because mine picks it up. `which gradle` gives `/usr/local/bin/gradle` and I also have `GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.11/`

Comment: how do I know how to define GRADLE_HOME ? Sorry I only know ios build for cordova. Gradle is new for me

Comment: Check where Gradle is installed: `which  gradle`